# How to upload an image by data uri to a upload file endpoint in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, form-data

I'm setting up a graphql server in nodejs. I have a mutation which takes an image data uri as an input and uploads the image to another server which accepts form data content.

I have tried using form-data library, but I think I'm missing something.

```
const FormData = require('form-data');

const uploadPhotoAsync = (dataUri, fileName) => {
  const content = Buffer.from(dataURI.split(',')[1]).toString('base64');

  const form = new FormData();
  form.append('file', content, fileName);

  await got(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: form.getHeaders(),
      body: form,
    });
}
```

I'm expecting the photo to be sent correclty but that's not the case. The base64 url I'm sending initially is not the same received when I decode it, so maybe the conversion is not correct

Comment: What is different about what is received?  How can you tell it is different?

Comment: The image is corrupted. I send the initial data uri to my nodejs server, and I decode the file received on the second server and they aren't the same.